# 'Could not find member 'type' on object of type 'PolicyParameter'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-policy

I having hard time with those Polcies and deployment through Azure Pipelines. Now it is expecting defined `type` when it is already defined.

I using Azure Policies Deploy Template (Create and assign task both have version 3)
Error message:

> InvalidRequestContent : The request content was invalid and could not
>   be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'type' on object of type
>   'PolicyParameter'. Path 'properties.parameters.envValue.type', line 9,
>   position 15.'.

Prof
[image]

What is wrong with my parameres file?

```
{
  "envValue": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Value",
      "description": "Deployment Environment of the resource"
    },
    "defaultValue": "Dev",
    "allowedValues": [
      "Dev",
      "Qas",
      "prd"
    ]
  }
}
```

My assignment task:

```
# Input variables: set these values in the variables section of the release pipeline

#   AssignmentName        - [required] Policy assignment name
#   AssignmentDisplayName - [optional] Policy assignment display name
#   AssignmentDescription - [optional] Policy assignment description
#   PolicyName            - [optional] Name of policy definition to assign
#   PolicySetName         - [optional] Name of policy set definition to assign
#   ResourceGroupName     - [optional] Name of resource group the policy [set] definition will be applied to
#   SubscriptionId        - [optional] Id of subscription the policy [set] definition will be applied to
#   ManagementGroupName   - [optional] Name of management group the policy [set] definition will be applied to
#  PolicyParameters      - [optional] Policy parameter values in JSON string format

# Notes:
#   Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/ for documentation on the Powershell cmdlets and the JSON input formats

$assignmentName = "$(AssignmentName)"
$assignmentDisplayName = "$(AssignmentDisplayName)"
$assignmentDescription = "$(AssignmentDescription)"
$policyName = "$(PolicyName)"
$policySetName = "$(PolicySetName)"
$resourceGroupName = "$(ResourceGroupName)"
$subscriptionId = "$(SubscriptionId)"
$managementGroupName = "$(managementGroupName)"
$policyParameters = "$(PolicyParameters)"

if (!$assignmentName)
{
    throw "Unable to create policy assignment: required input variable value `$(AssignmentName) was not provided"
}

if (!$policyName -and !$policySetName)
{
    throw "Unable to create policy assignment: neither `$(PolicyName) nor `$(PolicySetName) was provided. One or the other must be provided."
}

if ($policyName -and $policySetName)
{
    throw "Unable to create policy assignment: `$(PolicyName) '$policyName' and `$(PolicySetName) '$policySetName' were both provided. Either may be provided, but not both."
}

if ($subscriptionId -and $managementGroupName)
{
    throw "Unable to create policy assignment: `$(SubscriptionId) '$subscriptionId' and `$(ManagementGroupName) '$managementGroupName' were both provided. Either may be provided, but not both."
}

if ($managementGroupName -and $resourceGroupName)
{
    throw "Unable to create policy assignment: `$(ManagementGroupName) '$managementGroupName' and `$(ResourceGroupName) '$resourceGroupName' were both provided. Either may be provided, but not both."
}

if ($managementGroupName)
{
    $scope = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/$managementGroupName"
    $searchParameters = @{ManagementGroupName=$managementGroupName}
}
else
{
    if (!$subscriptionId)
    {
        $subscription = Get-AzureRmContext | Select-Object -Property Subscription
        $subscriptionId = $subscription.Id
    }

    $scope = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"
    $searchParameters = @{SubscriptionId=$subscriptionId}

    if ($resourceGroupName)
    {
        $scope += "/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName"
    }
}

$cmdletParameters = @{Name=$assignmentName; Scope=$scope}
if ($assignmentDisplayName)
{
    $cmdletParameters += @{DisplayName=$assignmentDisplayName}
}

if ($assignmentDescription)
{
    $cmdletParameters += @{Description=$assignmentDescription}
}

if ($policyName)
{
    $policyDefinition = Get-AzureRmPolicyDefinition @searchParameters | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $policyName }
    if (!$policyDefinition)
    {
        throw "Unable to create policy assignment: policy definition $policyName does not exist"
    }

    $cmdletParameters += @{PolicyDefinition=$policyDefinition}
}

if ($policySetName)
{
    $policySetDefinition = Get-AzureRmPolicySetDefinition @searchParameters | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $policySetName }
    if (!$policySetDefinition)
    {
        throw "Unable to create policy assignment: policy set definition $policySetName does not exist"
    }

    $cmdletParameters += @{PolicySetDefinition=$policySetDefinition}
}

if ($policyParameters)
{
    $cmdletParameters += @{PolicyParameter=$policyParameters}
}

&New-AzureRmPolicyAssignment @cmdletParameters
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda of late but I bumped into this today.
Your parameters file for the assignment should be like this:

```
{
 "envValue":{
    "value": "Dev"
  }
}
```

What you are passing is the parameter definition, not the actual parameter. Follow the same pattern as an ARM template.

Comment: This is the correct answer,  the way parameter file work is like passing values to the `main template`, instead of separating parameter definition from the `main template`. So you should keep definition in `main template` and provide values in the `parameter file`. If you know Terraform, it is like the relationship between values.tf and .tfvars.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like creating your policy definition task succeeded meaning that your parameters and rule should be already established. The issue is at assignment time meaning that you are probably sending the policy parameter not in a string format to the pipeline.

Comment: so where exactly problem is located? In powershell `@cmdletParameters` contains `PolicyDefinition` with object that contains such things as `PolicyDefinitionId` with path to the policy, `-PolicyParameter:` with path to `azurepolicy.parameters.json` etc.

Comment: From this command, I do not see where you are passing that json file. You should also double check the pipeline parameters to see if you are passing the correct policy parameters from there.